# asp.net webservice OnUnload?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, dispose, sqlconnection

I'm creating a web service which has a number of methods, all of which make use of a SqlConnection. It seems logical that I would declare a class level connection and initialise it in the web service constructor.

Problem is I cannot find a definitive way to release the connection when the web service call completes, so I have a connection leak. I've tried overriding the Dipose() method but it doesn't get called in a reasonable timeframe (actually not at all in my testing). For good measure I also tried attaching a handler to the Disposed() event but as expected same problem.

Is there nothing similar to Page.OnUnload for web service classes? It seems hard to believe I would have to establish a separate connection in every individual method.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

> It seems logical that I would declare a class level connection and initialise it in the web service constructor.

No, this doesn't seem logical at all. ADO.NET uses a [connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) so that you don't need to do this. This connection pool is per connection string per application domain.

So you could simply draw a new connection from the pool in each web method and return it to the pool at the end (the `using` statements will take care of this):

```
[WebMethod]
public void Foo()
{
    // Here you are NOT creating a new connection to the database
    // you are just drawing one from the connection pool
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(SomeConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        // Here you are NOT opening a new connection to the database
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id FROM foo";
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // do something with the results
            }
        }
    } // Here you are NOT closing the connection, you are just returning it to the pool
}
```

So here's an advice: don't try to manage connections manually by using some class fields, static fields, ... Leave this management to ADO.NET as it does it better.

Remark: The code I've shown usually resides in a data access layer which is called by the web method.

Comment: Thanks Darin, but this is actually what I was trying to avoid, i.e. having to decorate each method with a using{} block. I understand how connection pooling works, what I'm talking about is reducing code overhead in the webservice class. Since a connection object needs to be used in every method I was hoping to put the declaration in one place at class level and use a constructor / destructor (that was what I meant by logical). What you've described is what I'm currently using, I was hoping for a neater way I guess.

Comment: I should elaborate - I've had an assumption that a webservice class is instantiated once for each method call, and for each thread. What I was trying to achieve would depend on that being true. If that's NOT true then your example is the only way.